# ASP.NET multithreading problem with Timer

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, timer

I use code below to call web page every 24 hours. As I understand Timer.Elapsed event should be fired one time in 24 hours. Unfortunately sometimes timer.Elapsed fired several times in a row from different threads. Could anyone explain why this happens?

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = 1 };
    timer.Elapsed += delegate
                         {
                             SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Scheduler Timer");
                             timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds;
                             var webClient = new WebClient();
                             webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(WebHelper.GetBaseUrl + "/scheduled-task"));
                         };
    timer.Start();


}
```

Comment: Could it be that I must change start interval from Interval = 1 to something bigger like Interval = 1000?

Comment: Are you sure your site remains up for 24 hours (or longer)? IIS shuts down sites without traffic.

Comment: Is this happening inside of a web application?  It's generally not a good idea to use web applications for task scheduling.  A windows service or scheduled console app or something like that would be much more reliable.  The web app is at the mercy of the web server as to when it starts, how long it runs, etc.

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, it receives several hits in minutes.

Comment: @David I do not want to create separated app for schedule actions. I am sure I will find working solution in ASP.NET :) Even my solution above works good except that sometimes Timer.Elapsed event fits several times.

Comment: Can you add SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("App Starting"); at the beginning of the Application_Start and see whether is executes multiple times

Comment: @sll What are surprise! It seems Application_Start called three times.

Comment: @Tomas: looks like now you would be able to find out what is going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it related to restart IIS if it's public computer.
I know that timer does not work well in Application_Start event.

If you have posabillity I think you better create a window service or 
to put some variable LastRun DateTime and to check if it's already run today
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The Timer will basically fires based on the Interval you have given, your code is explaining that you have given an interval of '1' which will be taken in milli seconds(1 sec = 1000 milliseconds). Increase the interval to some more and also when a thread is in middle of one function, then also the timer will be called with out any stopping, so when the main thread enters inside a function make the timer like,

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
```

and after all the functionality again Enable the timer control. So, that it will not make the other functionalities affect.